# Website Crashed

Tags: php, javascript

I was getting the security alert--
"This page is accessing information that is not under its control. This poses a security risk. Do you want to continue?"

I added this script to my code---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myCallback = function( myParam ) {
    alert( "this was called across domains!" );
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://crossdomainhost/CrossDomainConsumerSite/Default.aspx?callback=myCallback&param=myParam></script>
```

My website got crashed.Does anyone has a solution to this?

Comment: it complains to crossdomainhost script

Comment: Cross domain is no fun.. http://easyxdm.net/wp/

Comment: your missing a quotation mark: `lback&param=myParam"></script>`

Comment: I am nort able to login to my website..so cant make changes.

Comment: If you can insert a call to an external script, you are able to insert your own script, unless: The external script is dynamic, or is not really your site. If indeed you have lost access to your hosting, that should be your main concern and not inject external code for integration in any site.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is not to run javascript from an external site.  Copy the script to your own server or don't use it.

This error message helps to reduce the risk of cross-site scripting and you probably don't want to be using any site that gives this message.  You certainly don't want this to be your site!